# Can I export all of my modified photos from Shotwell?

Tags: shotwell

Shotwell does non-destructive photo editing (it keeps the original file untouched while keeping a log of actions to generate an edited photo in a database).

However, I would like to easily backup all of my photos that I edited in Shotwell (what if that database is corrupt? what if I want to move to a different photo management program?).

Is there a way to select all modified photos and export them?

This is related to a Shotwell bug report ([Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/579808), [Upstream](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/1798)) currently in-progress, but I am looking for a way to work around that bug right now.

Comment: Note that Shotwell creates a new file '*_modified.jpg' for files you edit with an external editor. This doesn't help you with photos edited within Shotwell though. You can always export your entire library to a backup location, too. The catch is that you can't undo any edits from that point. Try just backing up your .shotwell folder for now and export any important edits to a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; there is a way of selecting only your modified files and exporting them all at once.

1) Within a single folder, modify each picture as needed, taking note of the file names of each.
2) Back out to the thumbnail view, esc. works for me. 
3) Select "View", then "Titles", or shift+ctrl+t, to view the file names with the thumbnails.
4) While holding the Control key, Select each of the modified pics individually, or select all if you have modified all of them.
5) Select "File" then "export" and go from there.  I choose to create a new folder within the same master folder called Modified, but that is up to you.

Try it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to select only modified images from within Shotwell.

There is a ticket for adding this as a saved search option -- which I think would work for you -- but that ticket hasn't seen an progress yet: http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4111

Comment: Thanks Eric. Is there a way to hack around this until that bug is resolved? Or am I at an impasse?

Answer (score 0):

You can select all modified photos by creating a saved search, and then choosing as a filter "Photo state" -> "has" -> "modifications" (sorry if words doesn't exactly match, I'm using a non-english version of Shotwell).

Then you can just select the results of this saved search, and export them wherever you like.